# How to write this Where clause in sequelize query?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

I have a SQL Server SELECT query and I want to convert it to Sequelize query builder:

```
SELECT ...
FROM usertbl as user
WHERE
[user].[is_deleted] = 0
        AND [user].[id_role] = 6
        AND ( LOWER([user].[cardid_print]) LIKE CONCAT('%', query_string, '%')
              OR LOWER([user].code) LIKE CONCAT('%', query_string, '%')
              OR LOWER([user].[firstname]) LIKE CONCAT('%', query_string, '%')
              OR LOWER([user].lastname) LIKE CONCAT('%', query_string, '%')
              OR LOWER([user].fullnameEN) LIKE CONCAT('%', query_string, '%')
              OR LOWER([user].firstname) LIKE CONCAT('%', query_string, '%')
              OR LOWER([user].idnumber) LIKE CONCAT('%', query_string, '%')
              OR CONCAT(LOWER([user].lastname), ' ', LOWER([user].firstname)) LIKE CONCAT('%', query_string, '%')
            )
```

How to convert it to sequelize query options object like this:

```
{
  where: { 
    is_deleted: 0,
    ...
  } 
}
```

or like this:

```
{
   where: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('FUNCTION',
            sequelize.col('field')), 'value')
}
```

### Edit 1:

- Query string nullable, if query string is null or empty string, remove where condition on it

### Edit 2:

- id_role nullable, like query_string

### Edit 3:

- I found this way without call LOWER/UPPER function [here](https://pastebin.com/1btH9nsf)
- I've tested this code and it work done!

Thank for your answer @ChuongTran

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it? And let me know :)

```
var sequelize = require('sequelize');
        var query_string = 'something..';
        var id_role = 6;
        var query = {
            is_deleted: 0
        }
        if(id_role !== undefined){
            query['id_role'] = id_role;
        }
        if(query_string !== undefined || query_string.length <= 0){
            query['$or'] = sequelize.literal(`( LOWER(cardid_print) LIKE CONCAT('%', ${query_string}, '%')
            OR LOWER(code) LIKE CONCAT('%', ${query_string}, '%')
            OR LOWER(firstname) LIKE CONCAT('%', ${query_string}, '%')
            OR LOWER(lastname) LIKE CONCAT('%', ${query_string}, '%')
            OR LOWER(fullnameEN) LIKE CONCAT('%', ${query_string}, '%')
            OR LOWER(firstname) LIKE CONCAT('%', ${query_string}, '%')
            OR LOWER(idnumber) LIKE CONCAT('%', ${query_string}, '%')
            OR CONCAT(LOWER(lastname), ' ', LOWER(firstname)) LIKE CONCAT('%', ${query_string}, '%')
          )`);
        }
        User.findAll({
            where: query
        })
        .then(users => {

        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('err', err);
        });
```